# Unix Script not executing in cron tab

Tags: unix

I am scheduling the below script in crontab and  it is not executing properly. But its executes properly if I run manually. could you please help me in fixing this issue. I tried in both lower environment and production also.

Thanks,
RD

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ROOTDIR=/opt/tp/01/buy/Serv
REMOTEUSER=app
SERVER=xxxxx.xxxx.xxx.xx
DATAPATH=/opt/tp/01/buy/Serv/transactionData/PO/incoming/
BACKUPPATH=/opt/tp/01/buy/Serv/transactionData/PO/processed/
------
--------
-------
```

Comment: Share your `crontab` command. Also, pass full path of this script in `cron` .

Comment: Below is the command i used in crontab

Comment: 00 20 * * * /opt/ptp/scripts/POAttachCommentNew.sh

Comment: you are not executing he shell script in crontab. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Execute in cron like below:

Pass the full path of the script.

```
00 20 * * * sh /opt/ptp/scripts/POAttachCommentNew.sh
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi..Sorry for late reply. I have tested your suggestion in dev and its working fine. Hope it will work in other environment as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept the answer. This lets the community know that you aren't looking for anymore answers.